# Spotify: Move to previous track without rewinding current one

Tags: linux, hotkeys, spotify

In the Spotify desktop client, pressing the "previous track" button or the corresponding hotkey after the current track has been playing for 3 seconds or more rewinds the track instead of actually moving to the previous track. Is there a way to disable this behaviour and instead move to the previous track unconditionally?

I am fine with defining a custom hotkey for this purpose. A quick-and-dirty hack is to simply issue the "previous track" command twice, e.g. what I'm currently using is

```
"playerctl previous && playerctl previous"
  XF86AudioPrev
```

in *.xbindkeysrc*. However, this is a less than ideal solution because if the current track has been playing for less than 3 seconds, then this will skip two tracks instead of one.